# Threading synchronization - balking pattern

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

```
 public class Example {
    private boolean jobInProgress = false;

    public void job() {
        lock(this) {
           if (jobInProgress) {
               return;
           }
           jobInProgress = true;
        }
        // Code to execute job goes here
        // ...
    }

    void jobCompleted() {
        lock(this) {
            jobInProgress = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I got this piece of code from Wikipedia and i have one thing i am not sure of.

Why `jobInProgress = true;` is not set inside the locked block just after the return statement? To be more explicit i will try to give a scenario:

- One thread gets the lock while others are waiting
- It releases the lock but before executing jobInProgress = true;, one of the waiting threads gets the lock and tests the condition which is still false. 
  Is this a feasible scenario or am i not getting the flow of execution right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing yourself:

```
lock(this) {
    if (jobInProgress) {
        return;
    } // <= closing brace of if

    // INSIDE LOCK, OUTSIDE IF
    jobInProgress = true;
} // <= closing brace of lock
```

I'll note that on the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balking_pattern):

```
public void job() {
    synchronized(this) {
       if (jobInProgress) {
           return;
       }

       // INSIDE LOCK, OUTSIDE IF
       jobInProgress = true;
    }
    // Code to execute job goes here
    // ...
}
```

it is exactly the same!

Comment: Ah, damn, i got the parentheses all wrong. Thanks for solving my blindness.